# VBA: Copy below row 3 and paste at the bottom of another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy all rows below Row 3 in sheet2 and paste them below the last row in sheet 1. I don't want to use 'Activesheet" like I have below. Is there another way to accomplish this?

(This doesn't work):

```
Rows("3:3").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(x1Down)).Select
Selection.Copy

Sheets("sheet1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(x1Down)).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("mySheet") 'change name as needed

With ws
   'assumes data is in a "table" format with all data rows in column A and data columns in row 1
   Dim lRow as Long, lCol as Long
   lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 
   lCol = .Cells(1,.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

   .Range(.Range("A4"),.Cells(lRow,lCol)).Copy _
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

End With
```

Comment: I don't want to copy over the first 3 rows. Only everything below row three. How can I account for that?

Comment: I am receiving an error: "Object doesn't support this property or method" and highlighted is the last row of code. "Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

Comment: @quenny - see edit and try again, sorry for sloppiness :(

Comment: In the second to last line of code, where does the closing parentheses go? I think " .Range(.Range("A4"),.Cells(lRow,lCol).Copy _" Is missing one

Comment: @quenny - ugh! before the `.Copy`. I fixed.